# How to implement retained backing on NSOpenGLView?

Tags: cocoa, opengl

I'm porting an iPad app to desktop and would like to figure out where and how to setup the equivalent of "kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking". I'm using NSOpenGLView right now. Let me know if I should be using something else.

Comment: What do you need the specific properties of retained backing for? If it's image persistence, as long as you don't use `glClear()` the contents of an NSOpenGLView should hang around and let you keep drawing over them. glReadPixels should also work just fine with the default NSOpenGLView when drawing to the standard framebuffer.

Comment: @BradLarson I feel silly now. I didn't even try that! The backing property was such a key thing to get it working on the iOS that I simply assumed it would be the same on the desktop. I just couldn't find any examples. Thanks for pointing out the obvious!